# How to find this greatest common divisor limit?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, contest-math

> Let $A^n-I=\begin{bmatrix}
> a_{n}&b_{n}\\
> c_{n}&d_{n}
> \end{bmatrix}
> $, where $A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 3&2\\
> 4&3
> \end{bmatrix}$, $I=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1&0\\
> 0&1
> \end{bmatrix}$ and let $f_{n}=\gcd(a_{n},b_{n},c_{n},d_{n})$.
>
> Show that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}=\infty$$

My idea:
I think we first have to find $A^n$, and this has a nice solution? Thank you.

Comment: Well why don't you try your idea? What is $A^n$?

Comment: meaning $A^n=A^{n-1}\cdot A=\cdots$,

Comment: Diagonalize $A$ first. That gives you a formula for $A^n$. It will involve a lot of $\sqrt2$:s, so you still have work to do! Or may be there is a clever trick? How far have you calculated this sequence?

Comment: yes,I try $f(\lambda)=(\lambda-3-\sqrt{2})(\lambda-3+\sqrt{2})$,But following is very ugly,Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: I think that the eigenvalues are $3\pm2\sqrt2$. It becomes a bit hairy, but at least you will get a better idea, what you need to prove.

Comment: Where is this problem from? Working it out was a lof of fun!

Comment: Oh,This problem from http://www.math.nsysu.edu.tw/~problem/

Answer (score 5):

We have the equation $A=B^2$ where
$$
B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\2&1\end{array}\right).
$$

Let
$$
B^n=\left(\begin{array}{cc}x_n&y_n\\z_n&x_n\end{array}\right).
$$
As $\det B^n=(-1)^n$, we know that $x_n^2=z_ny_n+(-1)^n.$ An easy induction
also proves that $z_n=2y_n$ for all $n$.

Assume first that $n$ is odd. I claim that $2x_n$ then divides all the entries of $A^n-I$. This is because
$$
A^n=(B^n)^2=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}x_n^2+y_nz_n&2x_ny_n\\ 2x_nz_n&x_n^2+y_nz_n\end{array}\right)
$$
Here $y_nz_n=x_n^2+1$, so we get that
$$
A^n-I=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2x_n^2&2x_ny_n\\ 2x_nz_n&2x_n^2\end{array}\right)
$$
proving the claim.

Assume then that $n$ is even. This time I claim that all the entries of $A^n-I$ are divisible by $2y_n$. For even $n$ we have $y_nz_n=x_n^2-1$, so the above calculation shows that
$$
A^n-I=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2y_nz_n&2x_ny_n\\ 2x_nz_n&2y_nz_n\end{array}\right)
$$
proving the claim.

It is easy to prove that both $x_n,y_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Your claim follows from this.

Comment: A different trick worked in the end. The key was to calculate those damn gcds for low $n$. After coming up with the matrix $B$ and writing down its low powers it became easy to connect the dots.

Comment: It's very nice! Thank you my frend @Jyrki Lahtonen

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $$b_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}+d_{n-1},~~c_n=2b_n,~~a_n=d_n=\sqrt{1+b_nc_n}$$

And for $a_n$ see [A001541](http://oeis.org/A001541), for $b_n$ see [A001542](http://oeis.org/A001542). I hope besides to complete elegant answer of @Jyrki; this help you also.

Comment: @math110: I am still thinking about Jyrki's suggestion. A magic trick!

Comment: +++$\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you ,I find this problem is PIN 54  (1995 Putnam Mathematical Competition Problems)

Comment: @Babak: Is that David Suchet (perhaps best known for his roles as Hercule Poirot) in your avatar?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yes Mon Ami ;-) Exactly. I love the way he always solve the cases. :-)