# How to write $[(2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n + (2+\sqrt{3})^{n+1} + (2-\sqrt{3})^{n+1}]/6$ to the form $a^2 + 2 b^2$ ($a, b \in \mathbb{N}$).

Tags: recurrence-relations

We know that $(2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n$ is an integer ([See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1903099)).

However, we want to write the formula
\begin{align}
&\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{6} (2+\sqrt{3})^n + \frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{6} (2-\sqrt{3})^n\\
&=\frac{1}{6} \left[(2+\sqrt{3})^{n+1} + (2-\sqrt{3})^{n+1} + (2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n\right]
\end{align}
to the form
$$a^2 + 2\,b^2,\ (a, b \in \mathbb{N}).$$

How?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Call the formula $f(n)$.  Can you prove for $n$ even $f(n)=f(n/2)^2+2x^2$ and for $n$ odd $f(n)=f((n-1)/2)^2+2y^2$?

Comment: The two irrational numbers $2\pm\sqrt{3}$ are roots of the quadratic equation $x^2= 4x-1$. So if we define a recurrence relation $(a_n)$ by the recurrence $$a_{n+2}:=4a_{n+1}-a_n$$ with initial conditions $a_0:=2$ and $a_1:=4$, then clearly $a_n\in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\geq 0$, and yet "routine" combinatorial analysis gives
$$a_n = (2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n$$
for all $n$. This proves that these numbers are actually integers. Now try the same technique on the number that you're interested it --- usually these linear combinations of powers of algebraic numbers give linear recurrences.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Well done! But how did you come up with that idea? Even though I may have seen something similar, there seems to be a hole in my education :-)

Comment: Yummy, can you tell us more about the origin of this problem? May be you can also take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619)?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  thank you for the compliment!  Do you remember learning a relationship between the $2n^{th}$ Fibonacci number and the ${n-1}$ and $n^{th}$ Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes! And I did notice that your  $x$-sequence (and $y$) comes from the same recurrence. I was trying to find a solution modelled after [this oldie](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/373416/11619), but couldn't make it match. Then missus called me to have my morning oats :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: This is a problem comes from my friend. Therefore, I don't know the origin. Thank you for your advice, and I will learn how to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(n)= 
\dfrac{3+\sqrt{3}}{6} (2+\sqrt{3})^n + \dfrac{3-\sqrt{3}}{6} (2-\sqrt{3})^n$ and $g(n)=\dfrac{\sqrt3} 6(2+\sqrt3)^n-\dfrac{\sqrt3}6(2-\sqrt3)^n$.

Can you show $f(n)^2+2\times g(n)^2=f(2n)$ and $f(n)^2+2\times g(n+1)^2=f(2n+1)?$

Comment: Helpful hints: $ (2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)=1; (3\pm\sqrt3)^2=6(2\pm\sqrt3)$

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you get this method? This is really amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Call your formula $f(n)$. Since $2\pm\sqrt{3}$ are the roots of $x^2-4x+1$, it's easy to show that $f(n)$ is  determined by $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=3$ and the recursive relation $f(n+1)=4f(n)-f(n-1)$.

After looking at @J.W.Tanner comment, I found out that we actually have
\begin{align*}
f(2n)&=f(n)^2+2\left(\sum_{0\leq k\leq n-1}f(k)\right)^2\\
f(2n+1)&=f(n)^2+2\left(\sum_{0\leq k\leq n}f(k)\right)^2
\end{align*}
Now, I don't really know how difficult is to prove this by induction, but it is an interesting pattern.